# Dual objects where only one zig-zag identity holds?

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples, duality-theorems, monoidal-categories

Recall the definition of a (left) [dual object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dualizable+object) in a monoidal category.
If one requires that both the evaluation and the coevaluation are isomorphisms, one zig-zag-identity implies the other (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4434976/terminology-one-sided-adjoint-equivalence/4507658#4507658)).
Is this still true if one drops the requirement that both evaluation and coevaluation are isomorphisms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough for evaluation and coevaluation to be both monomorphisms or both epimorphisms, depending on which zig-zag identity you're inferring from which.

Indeed, consider 2-monomorphisms $\eta\colon\mathrm{id}_C\Rightarrow GF$, $\epsilon\colon FG\Rightarrow\mathrm{id}_D$ satisfying $\epsilon F\circ F\eta=\mathrm{id}_F$.

Using that $\epsilon$ is a monomorphism, we get that $\epsilon\circ F(G\epsilon\circ\eta G)=(\epsilon\circ FG\epsilon)\circ\eta G=(\epsilon\circ \epsilon FG)\circ F\eta G=\epsilon\circ(\epsilon F\circ F\eta)G=\epsilon$ implies $F(G\epsilon\circ\eta G)=\mathrm{id}_{FG}$.

Using that $\eta G$ is a monomorphism, we then get that $\eta G=GF(G\epsilon\circ\eta G)\circ\eta G=\eta G\circ(G\epsilon\circ\eta G)$ implies $G\epsilon\circ\eta G=\mathrm{id}_G$.